# Photoswipe Android mobile - Image flickering

Tags: android, photoswipe

Im using photoswipe for my mobile webpage to display swipping images

One issue I found and its really having an impact on Android user experience.

Here an example: 
http://goo.gl/8181XB

When swiping between images, let say Image X to Image Y, Image Y shows up shortly then turns to black (i think the image is getting transparent or the background is getting over the image) for some milliseconds and then shows up again correctly. Im testing basically on Android 4.4.4 and 4.2.2 with the latest version of Photoswipe.

I searched the web but no clue. 
Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: anyone who has the same issue ?

Comment: The link you gave does not contain PhotoSwipe as far as I can see.